# Why isn't a superposition just classical uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, superposition

I have read a little about Quantum computing.

From what I understand, Quantum Superposition is when a qubit is in a state $\alpha|0\rangle$ + $\beta|1\rangle$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are probability amplitudes. Now when we try to measure or see the qubit it collapses to a 0 or 1.

Why don't we consider that the electron is in either the 0 or 1 state in superposition but we don't know which state because we haven't measured it yet.

I'll give you an example. I ask a friend to go inside a closed room and flip a coin. Now I know that it's either heads or tails with equal probability. So, can I say that the coin is in the superposition state $\sqrt0.5|heads\rangle$ + $\sqrt0.5|tails\rangle$ ?

I then ask my friend to dope the coin so it has a higher chance (0.75) of falling heads up. So, can I say that the coin is in a superposition $\sqrt0.75|heads\rangle$ + $\sqrt0.25|tails\rangle$ ?

Then I go inside the room and suddenly I see the coin. So can I say it's state collapsed to a heads or tails because I measured it?

Comment: Possibly related - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39354/classical-vs-qubits-superposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I have an electron.  There are various states it *could* be in.  The states where we have a definite spin component are

$|z_{UP}\rangle$
 z component of its spin is pointing upwards

$|z_{DOWN}\rangle$
 z component of its spin is pointing downwards

$|x_{RIGHT}\rangle$
 x component of its spin is pointing to the right

$|x_{LEFT}\rangle$
 x component of its spin is pointing to the left

(we'll ignore the y direction).  Now a [Stern Gerlach apparatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) gives us a means for measuring these spin components - if we orient the apparatus in the z plane its powerful magnets separate incoming electrons so that the ones it's measured as z-spin-up go upwards and the ones as z-spin-down go downwards.

Now suppose I have an incoming beam of electrons, where I've prepared them so that 50% of them are z-spin-up and 50% are z-spin-down.  (I could do this by using a previous Stern Gerlach apparatus, measuring the z spins then recombining the beam).  This is a *mixture*, not a superposition.  If I now do my z measurement, I find 50% in z-spin-up and 50% in z-spin-down as I expect.

If, instead of the mixture, my electrons are in a true superposition state, say $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|z_{UP}\rangle + |z_{DOWN}\rangle)$$  Then when I do my measurement, I again measure 50% as z-spin-up and 50% as z-spin-down.  These, however are *not the same thing*:

Suppose I reorient my Stern Gerlach apparatus to this time measure the x spin.  To see what will happen you need the relations $$ |z_{UP}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x_{RIGHT}\rangle + |x_{LEFT}\rangle)$$  $$ |z_{DOWN}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x_{RIGHT}\rangle - |x_{LEFT}\rangle)$$  For the case where the incoming particles are in the z mixture, I'll get 50% x-spin-right and 50% x-spin-left.

For the superposition case though $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|z_{UP}\rangle + |z_{DOWN}\rangle)$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x_{RIGHT}\rangle + |x_{LEFT}\rangle) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x_{RIGHT}\rangle - |x_{LEFT}\rangle)\}$$  $$=|x_{RIGHT}\rangle $$

So I'll get 100% x-spin-right.

In the coin example, we have a mixture, not a superposition.  The reason macroscopic objects behave as mixtures rather than superpositions is generally explained by the phenomenon of [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence).

Comment: Can we consider superposition as a fast spinning coin in a frictionless environment, final state of which will depend on how we catch it? Note that in this case the coin is confined to two distinct values, i.e. digital. Or is it something like two pictures gradually transforming to each other, having infinitely many pictures in between, i.e. analog, but our observation/measurement forcing them to rest in only one stable picture/final state?